# Close open resource handles returned from Deno APIs before finishing test case

Tags: deno

I'm getting this error message:

```
Make sure to close all open resource handles returned from Deno APIs before 
finishing test case.
```

When I'm running this Deno testing function:

```js
import { assertEquals } from "https://deno.land/std/testing/asserts.ts";

Deno.test("fetch example", async function (): Promise<void> {
    await fetch("http://www.google.com.br").then(data => {
        console.log('completed')
    });
    assertEquals("world", "world");
});
```

The command I use to run it is:

```sh
deno test --allow-net
```

I looked at the [documentation](https://github.com/denoland/deno/tree/master/std/testing) but I wasn't able to find a way to solve it.

This is the complete error stack:

```
$ deno test --allow-net
Compile file:///<my_path>/isolated_test.ts
running 1 tests
test fetch example ... completed
FAILED (199ms)

failures:

fetch example
AssertionError: Test case is leaking resources.
Before: {
  "0": "stdin",
  "1": "stdout",
  "2": "stderr"
}
After: {
  "0": "stdin",
  "1": "stdout",
  "2": "stderr",
  "3": "httpBody"
}

Make sure to close all open resource handles returned from Deno APIs before 
finishing test case.
    at Object.assert ($deno$/util.ts:33:11)
    at Object.resourceSanitizer [as fn] ($deno$/testing.ts:81:5)
    at async TestApi.[Symbol.asyncIterator] ($deno$/testing.ts:264:11)
    at async Object.runTests ($deno$/testing.ts:346:20)

failures:

        fetch example

test result: FAILED. 0 passed; 1 failed; 0 ignored; 0 measured; 0 filtered out (199ms)
```

My deno version

```sh
$ deno --version
deno 1.0.2
v8 8.4.300
typescript 3.9.2
```

Comment: updated my answer. You'll be able to add a timeout to automatically close the body once `AbortController` is supported in `fetch`

Comment: nice, i'll try to remmember that

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Deno tests checks for resource handles that were not closed properly during a test.

In order to fix your test, you need to consume the response body, since internally uses a resource handle. A simple way would be to call `.text` or any other of the methods to consume the body: `arrayBuffer`, `json`, `formData`, `blob`

```
Deno.test("fetch example", async function (): Promise<void> {
    const res = await fetch("http://www.google.com.br")
    await res.text(); // Consume the body so the file handle is closed
    assertEquals("world", "world");
});
```

You can see that one of the resource handles is `httpBody`:

```
After: {
  "0": "stdin",
  "1": "stdout",
  "2": "stderr",
  "3": "httpBody"
}
```

Currently, there's no way to disregard the body since Deno's `fetch` does not support `AbortController`.

Deno only closes automatically the resource handle if the status code is one of `301, 302, 303, 307, 308`

### Update

As of Deno `1.0.3`, `Response.body` is now a `ReadableStream` ([PR #5787](https://github.com/denoland/deno/pull/5787)) and the resource handle can be closed calling `res.body.cancel();

```
Deno.test("fetch example", async function (): Promise<void> {
     const res = await fetch("http://www.google.com.br")
     await res.body.cancel(); // Cancel the body so the file handle is closed
     assertEquals("world", "world");
});
```